# C program. I have 2 Timestamp which is of char * in the format %d/%d/%d/%d/%d. i want to find the difference between them.

Tags: c, timestamp

> First of all both the timestamp should be in this format
>   yyyy/mmm/hh/mm/ss and error should pop up when they are not in this
>   format.
>   Also i want to find the difference between them.
>
> eg. if time1 = 2000/034/08/12/00
>   time2 = 2000/034/07/12/00
>   TIME = time1 - time2
>   TIME = 60 minutes

```
if (sscanf(now,"%d/%d/%d/%d/%d",&year,&month,&hour,&min,&sec) != 5)     //Error - If enter more than 5 numbers still give correct answer    //CHECKING IF THE ARGUMENT IS CORRECT OR NOT
        {   
            fprintf(stderr,"\x1b[1;31mMust specify correct timestamp format\nExiting........\x1b[0m\n");
            exit(1);    
        }
```

Comment: Since "mmm" is 3 digits, you probably are talking about the julian day for the year - the number of the day since the start of the year [1..365/366].

Comment: how should i convert that char* into the julian date calendar